Understanding そのまま in 素直にそのまま言う
I am not certain about the meaning of そのまま here:

It seems like she doesn't like what she was told and wished him to be more gentle/honest and bring up examples in more objective manner (そのまま)?
I have doubts on what particle should go after そのまま. Is it を or に? I think the latter is more likely and I want to confirm.

素直にそのまま言う in this context means 素直に言いたいことをそのまま言う, or "to say what one wants to say just as it is". That is, it refers to the opposite attitude of saying バカ or 殺してやる to someone you like. You have to infer the implied object of 言う, which shouldn't be difficult because there is 素直に.
Nothing is omitted after そのまま. It works as an adverb on its own.
